# Is there a way to change the tab icon of the browser in GWT?

Tags: gwt, browser, favicon

In `GWT`, there is a way to change the tab title `Window.setTitle("new Title")` but is there a way to change the window icon (or the tab icon)?

**PS:** I know it can be done by adding this code to the head of your html page:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
```

But what if, I want to change the tab icon dynamically? can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Chrome and Firefox with `canvas`.